# How to hide the google's search box in the webview

Tags: android, android-webview

Just like the [APUS launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apusapps.launcher), when using the webview to load the Google webpage, it hides the search box in the webview, also in another search engine such as Baidu. So my question is how to hide the google's search box in the webview.

[image]

Comment: where is it hiding google's search box in above image? I am not getting it.

Comment: Darpan, check the screenshot again, thanks.

Comment: load that page in any desktop browser, figure out what class/div this box is in. And create a javascript function to hide it, and load that functinos in `loadUrl("javascript:yourFunction()");`

Comment: I have tried, but not work. I put these code in the onPageFinished function: view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"
     + "document.getElementById('mngb').style.display ='none';"
     + "})()");